# Does application Spring4Shell- CVE-2022-22965 vulnerable if using spring-plugin-core : 1.2.0?

Tags: java, spring

Is the system affected by CVE-2022-22965 if it only uses spring-plugin-core from the mentioned impacted list?

Configuration

- java 8
- Spring boot : 2.2.6.RELEASE
- Packaged as executable JAR
- spring-plugin-core : 1.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick search for Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE shows the maven repository with all vulnerabilities listed:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: So even if I m  not using Java 9/9+ or Not traditional war my system is vulnerable is it?

Comment: "A Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux application running on JDK 9+ may be vulnerable to remote code execution (RCE) via data binding. The specific exploit requires the application to run on Tomcat as a WAR deployment. If the application is deployed as a Spring Boot executable jar, i.e. the default, it is not vulnerable to the exploit. However, the nature of the vulnerability is more general, and there may be other ways to exploit it."

Comment: So Java 8 wouldn't be affected, but I would suggest starting with Java 17 and use a newser version of Spring Boot instead to circumvent other possibilities of exploiting CVE-2022-22965. 

I guess you mean CVE-2022-22965 as I couldn't find something about CVE-2022-2296.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes, I meant CVE-2022-22965.